# Analysing electron diffraction

Tags: electrons, diffraction

In analysing photon diffraction by a single slit we add up a series of electric field phasors. Is there a similar method for analysing electron diffraction by a single slit?

Comment: Take a Fourier transform of the slit (just like for the optical case).

Answer (score 0):

The time-independent Schrödinger equation within a constant potential (zero, for convenience) is the Helmholtz equation:
$$\nabla^2\psi+k^2\psi=0$$
where $k=\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}$ and $E$ is the electron energy. This is the same equation that monochromatic radiation obeys:
$$\nabla^2\vec{E}+k^2\vec{E}=0$$
where $k=\omega\sqrt{\mu \epsilon}$ is the wave vector magnitude.

Because of this, you would expect similar diffraction patterns for electrons and radiation of similar wavelengths, and can apply the same method to the electron wavefunction.

There are caveats that could cause differences in practice. Here are some:

1. The boundary conditions for radiation and the electron wavefunction at the slit are not necessarily the same, but assuming the waves are "blocked" by the slits in similar ways, e.g. in ways that doesn't depend much on e.g. what the slits are made of, the difference in the wave solutions should be small.
2. The Schrödinger equation is a scalar equation, while the Helmholtz equation for radiation is a vector equation. The electron flux is proportional to $|\psi|^2$ while the radiation intensity is proportional to the component of $\text{Re}\{\vec{E}\times\vec{H}^*\}$ perpendicular to the screen. In a typical single-slit diffraction experiment, the TE and TM polarizations behave similarly and their intensities add (approximately), so you see a similar pattern regardless of polarization.
3. The incident waves can be different, depending on what kind of sources you use, but as long as the waves look enough like "plane waves" by the time they reach the slit, this should not matter much.

Comment: Light maxima in double slit interference occur where the electric fields are in phase. For electrons is there a quantity analogous to electric field so that maxima occur where that quantity is in phase for electrons coming through the two slits?

Comment: Yes, the wavefunction.